# Other Aggregate Functions method not work in my laravel 8 project

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have laravel project with laravel framework version 8.11.2.
when i want to work with [Other Aggregate Functions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions) like withSum() show me error

**My code:**

```
       $buyInvoice=BuyInvoice::Where([
        ['provider_id',$validatedData['ProviderCode']],
        ['InvoiceDate','>',$fromDate],
        ['InvoiceDate','<',$ToDate],
    ])->withSum('jewelsItems', 'weight')
         ->orderBy('jewelsItems_sum_weight')
         ->get();
```

Description : I am trying to sum weights of all jewelsItem have in Common invoice that i found with some conditions and store it in new column for each invoice.

Point: I don't want to use [Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions) cause of theirs vulnerabilities

**Models:**

1.jewelItem model:

```
    protected $table = 'jewel_items';

public function jewel(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Jewel');
}

public function buyInvoice(){
    return $this->belongsTo(BuyInvoice::class,'buy_invoice_id');
}
```

2.buyInvoice model:

```
    protected $table = 'buy_invoices';

public function provider(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Provider::class,'provider_id');
}

public function jewelsItems(){
return $this->hasMany(JewelsItem::class,'buy_invoice_id');
}
```

**Error:**

```
Call to undefined method App\Models\BuyInvoice::withSum()
```

Is it related to my framework?.
How can i fix this completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a new enough version of Laravel 8.

> Release Notes for 8.x
>
> `v8.12.0` (2020-10-29)
> ...
> Added `withMax()`|`withMin()`|`withSum()`|`withAvg()` methods to `Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships` (#34965,
> f4e4d95, #35004) ...

You need at least version `8.12.0`.